# Storing Time-Series Data of different resolution in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am wondering if anyone knows a good way to store time series data of different time resolutions in DynamoDB.

For example, I have devices that send data to DynamoDB every 30 seconds. The individual readings are stored in a Table with the unique device ID as the Hash Key and a timestamp as the Range Key.

I want to aggregate this data over various time steps (30 mins, 1 hr, 1 day etc.) using a lambda and store the aggregates in DynamoDB as well. I then want to be able to grab any resolution data for any particular range of time, 48 30 minute aggregates for the last 24hrs for instance, or each daily aggregate for this month last year.

I am unsure if each new resolution should have its own tables, `data_30min`, `data_1hr` etc or if a better approach would be something like making a composite Hash Key by combining the resolution with the Device ID and storing all aggregate data in a single table.

For instance if the device ID is `abc123` all 30 minute data could be stored with the Hash Key `abc123_30m` and the 1hr data could be stored with the HK `abc123_1h` and each would still use a timestamp as the range key.

What are some pros and cons to each of these approaches and is there a solution I am not thinking of which would be useful in this situation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've seen this page from the tech docs regarding Be[st Practices for storing time series data in DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-time-series.html). It talks about splitting your data into time periods such that you only have one "hot" table where you're writing and many "cold" tables that you only read from.

Regarding the primary/sort key selection, you should probably use a coarse timestamp value as the primary key and the actual timestamp as a sort key. Otherwise, if your periods are coarse enough, or each device only produces a relatively small amount of data then your idea of using the device id as the hash key could work as well.

Generating pre-aggregates and storing in DynamoDb would certainly work though you should definitely consider having separate tables for the different granularities you want to support. Beware of mutating data. As long as all your data arrives in order and you don't need to recompute old data, then storing pre-aggregated time series is fine but if data can mutate, or if you have to account for out-of order/late arriving data then things get complicated.

You may also consider a relational database for the "hot" data (ie. last 7 days, or whatever period makes sense) and then, running a batch process to pre-aggregate and move the data into cold, read-only DynamoDB tables, with DAX etc.